login url for Saml 2.0 is not working after migration to spring boot 3.3.4 from 2.7.18
Describe the bug
I've migrated from spring boot 2.7.18 to spring boot 3.3.4, I've a SAML 2.0 with OpenSaml in my project, previously I used to redirect to the SAML login page using /login/saml2/sso/okta but after migrating the URL is not working and is directly returning 404, I've checked and found that request is directly going to Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationRequestFilter and then to the OpenSamlAuthenticationRequestResolver.resolve(-,-) and using request matcher for \saml2\authenticate\{registrationId} and since the login url does not match the authentication is set as null
it's giving below page, no relying party defination found is because of favicon.icon call igonore it I've checked and relying party configs are already present
image
Here is stack trace
Saml2AuthenticationException{error=[relying_party_registration_not_found] No relying party registration found}
    at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.authentication.Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:231)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationRequestFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:384)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:905)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

To Reproduce
here is the saml github POC project,
https://github.com/shubhamwankh/SamlPoc
to reproduce make http://localhost:8080/login/saml2/sso/okta
Expected behavior
after hitting above url it should redirect to okta login page

With your sample application I have no issue hitting the login URL. I'm redirect to https://dev-17729161.okta.com/app/dev-17729161_springbootsaml_1/exkkfo143htDBx2aV5d7/sso/saml which displays the okta login form.

btw 3.0 is not a valid version for springboot, I had to change it to 3.2.10. Did you already try to run your sample application ?

@Gilles I'm using spring boot 3.3.4 and while hitting normal url http://localhost:8080 works fine which redirects to the login url but hitting http://localhost:8080/login/saml2/sso/okta gives error, this later url is used everywhere we are reluctant to use any other url's
the same thing was working with spring boot 2.7.18

You should use http://localhost:8080/saml2/authenticate/okta the /login/saml2/sso/okta is used to authenticate the asserting party response.

If you really want to change the URL I guess that you will have to implement a SamlAuthenticationRequestResolver and set a custom request matcher (see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/login/authentication-requests.html#servlet-saml2login-sp-initiated-factory-custom-authnrequest), but I think you will also have to change the processing URL for the IDP response: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/login/authentication.html#saml2-response-processing-endpoint
